# How can I disable Kies in Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies

Whenever I connect my S2 to the power outlet (not to a computer), the Kies application pops up. Where do I disable this auto-activation?

Comment: Samsung Kies is one of the worst pieces of software I think I've ever come across. I had to install it to upgrade my mother's SGS, I was astonished by how much it clogged up my system (3 separate autorun entries, 2 services), and how unbearably slow it was.

Comment: @fredley Kies Mini is a lot better, just a small standalone app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **Applications** > **Development** > and check **USB debugging**

After that if you connect your S2 to a PC it will connect in USB mode and you won't get the KIES application popup.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's something funny with either your USB cable, the charger or the socket on your phone that's causing it to detect it as a full PC connection, rather than just a dumb charger.

You should be able to get rid of that prompt for the moment by going into **Settings** -> **Wireless and Network** -> **USB Settings** and selecting the **Mass Storage** mode rather than the **Samsung Kies** mode.

However you really ought to try with another charger and cable to see if that fixes the actual problem, pure-charger cables shouldn't be detected as a PC, the signal on the cable is different and the phone should detect that.

Comment: I don't have USB Settings under Wireless and Network.

Comment: @ripper sorry you must be running a different update then, I know Samsung have moved that setting around at times. Have a look under the other headings in Settings to see if you can see the USB settings, I think it might have been under the SD Card and phone settings in the past too?

Comment: haven't found it.